# dotnet restore/build fails on linux with error MSB3202, the project file "PARENT_DIR/YYY.proj" was not found [PARENT_DIR/YYY.sln]

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core

I am building simple .net core solution which contains two projects. Here's the sln file

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.32930.78
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "DataAccess", "DataAccess\DataAccess.csproj", "{A2215C05-2906-47D8-A51E-986167EED172}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Common", "Common\Common.csproj", "{5D3617CC-A0CC-437F-96CC-D64B6F23A668}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {A2215C05-2906-47D8-A51E-986167EED172}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {A2215C05-2906-47D8-A51E-986167EED172}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {A2215C05-2906-47D8-A51E-986167EED172}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {A2215C05-2906-47D8-A51E-986167EED172}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {A2215C05-2906-47D8-A51E-986167EED172}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {A2215C05-2906-47D8-A51E-986167EED172}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {A2215C05-2906-47D8-A51E-986167EED172}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {A2215C05-2906-47D8-A51E-986167EED172}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {5D3617CC-A0CC-437F-96CC-D64B6F23A668}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5D3617CC-A0CC-437F-96CC-D64B6F23A668}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5D3617CC-A0CC-437F-96CC-D64B6F23A668}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5D3617CC-A0CC-437F-96CC-D64B6F23A668}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5D3617CC-A0CC-437F-96CC-D64B6F23A668}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {5D3617CC-A0CC-437F-96CC-D64B6F23A668}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {5D3617CC-A0CC-437F-96CC-D64B6F23A668}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {5D3617CC-A0CC-437F-96CC-D64B6F23A668}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {5EECAB02-1A61-4FAD-9E00-5B1292E418E6}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

When I run dotnet restore/build from the solution directory on my Windows machine, everything goes as expected and the output is the following

```
dotnet build
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Common -> C:\git\Common\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\Common.dll
  Common -> C:\git\Common\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Common.dll
  DataAccess -> C:\git\DataAccess\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\DataAccess.dll
Build succeeded.

    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.08
```

When I am trying to run the same process from the Docker container it fails with the following message

```
PS /App> pwd

Path
----
/App

PS /App> dotnet build
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/NuGet.targets(369,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/App/Common/Common.csproj" was not found. [/App/My.sln]

Build FAILED.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/NuGet.targets(369,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/App/Common/Common.csproj" was not found. [/App/My.sln]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.24
```

I am running the process on

```
PS /> cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

**EDIT 1**
Here is my Dockerfile content

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env

WORKDIR /App

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet nuget add source 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/_packaging/2bba9c97-9acb-40b5-aa6c-17e17617e3aa/nuget/v3/index.json' -u 'tst' -p 'XXXXXXXXX' --store-password-in-clear-text
RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y powershell
```

**EDIT 2**
If I am running the build on container from individual projects folder, not from solution directory it works as expected

```
PS /App/Common> pwd

Path
----
/App/Common

PS /App/Common> dotnet build
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Common -> /App/common/bin/Debug/netstandard2.1/Common.dll
  Common -> /App/common/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/Common.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.67
```

**EDIT 3**
I can also confirm that the project file exists inside the container

```
PS /> pwd

Path
----
/

PS /> ls /App/common/Common.csproj
/App/common/Common.csproj
```

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: Please see the EDIT 1 section.

Comment: Have you confirmed the file in question exists? Does running `ls /App/Common/Common.csproj` from within the container give you anything?

Comment: Hi @MattThalman, please see EDIT 2

Comment: **Edit 2** does not show if the file exists. It just shows that `dotnet build` passes. Maybe the project file is named differently? This would explain why `dotnet build` inside the dir passes, but building the solution fails - the latter mentions the project file explicitly. You should run the command Matt suggested, namely `ls /App/Common/Common.csproj`

Comment: ```PS /> ls /App/Common/Common.csproj
/App/Common/Common.csproj
```

Comment: @AlexeyAuslender - could you update the post? Add **EDIT 3** with this command?

Comment: Done @mark, please see **EDIT 3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was case sensitivity of the path.

```
C:\git\Common
```

vs

```
"Common\Common.csproj"
```

recorder in solution file